# One form with many submit buttons with PHP on a New DomDocument

Tags: php

My DomDocument will only put down 1 submit button. I need all buttons to be submits, but only the first one does and the rest are turned into textareas, even though I specify "submit".

I know i can do this with HTML, but DomDocuments only prints out 1 submit.

How can I have more then 1 submit button:

Code:

```
$tSForm = new DOMDocument;
$tSFRoot = $tSForm->createElement('Form', '');
$tSFId =  $tSForm->createAttribute('ID');
$tSFId->value = 'tSFORM';
$tSFRoot->appendChild($tSFId);
$tSFAction = $tSForm->createAttribute('Action');
$tSFAction->value = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$tSFRoot->appendChild($tSFAction);
$tSFMethod = $tSForm->createAttribute('Method');
$tSFMethod->value = 'POST';
$tSFRoot->appendChild($tSFMethod);

/// Create Button 1    
$tSFB1 = $tSForm->createElement('Input','');
$tSFB1Type = $tSForm->createAttribute('type');
$tSFB1Type->value = 'submit';
$tSFB1->appendChild($tSFB1Type);
$tSFB1Name = $tSForm->createAttribute('name');
$tSFB1Name->value = 'print';
$tSFB1->appendChild($tSFB1Name);
$tSFB1Name = $tSForm->createAttribute('value');
$tSFB1Name->value = 'PRINT';
$tSFB1->appendChild($tSFB1Name);
$tSFRoot->appendChild($tSFB1);
/// Create Button 2
$tSFB2 = $tSForm->createElement('Input','');
$tSFB2Type = $tSForm->createAttribute('type');
$tSFId->value = 'submit';
$tSFB2->appendChild($tSFB2Type);
$tSFB2Name = $tSForm->createAttribute('name');
$tSFB2Name->value = 'newTS';
$tSFB2->appendChild($tSFB2Name);
$tSFB2Name = $tSForm->createAttribute('value');
$tSFB2Name->value = 'New Time Sheet';
$tSFB2->appendChild($tSFB2Name);
$tSFRoot->appendChild($tSFB2);
/// Create Button3

$tSForm->appendChild($tSFRoot);
echo $tSForm->saveHTML();
```

Comment: You could condense a lot of that code and just have `$tSFB1->setAttribute('type', 'submit')` and so on. setAttribute() will create an attribute if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Thanks Dave Chen for cleaning up my code

Comment: trying that now Marc B.